# Socketio flutter cannot connect to heroku

Tags: node.js, flutter, heroku, socket.io

I am currently trying to conenct my flutter app to my socket.io server that I uploaded on heroku
I tried using both flutter_socket_io and socket_io_client but none is wokring. When I opened the logs on heroku server I am recieving a request for socket.io but for some reason nothing happens.

**The Log**

```
at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket" host=quarter-monkey.herokuapp.com request_id=5b59d08e-1f85-4d40-b6f1-cd6b75c41ba1 fwd="41.47.20.90" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2552ms status=101 bytes=129 protocol=https
```

My nodejs server code

```
require('./db/mongoose')


const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path')
const cors = require('cors')
const http = require('http')
const socketManager = require('./socket/socketManager');

//Different routes
const registerRouter = require('./routers/register.js')
const userRouter = require('./routers/user')
//Configuring the app
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

//#TODO Adjusting cors fore develpment
app.use(cors());
app.use('/register',registerRouter)
app.use('/user',userRouter)
const server = http.createServer(app);

socketManager(server);



server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log('Server is Up on', process.env.PORT)
})
```

Socket Manger

```
const socketIO = require('socket.io')



module.exports =  app => {
    const io =  socketIO(app);

  

        io.on('connection', async socket => {
        
        
            console.log("Connected");

  
    });

    return io;
};
```

My Flutter code

```
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as client;

class SocketHandler {
  static const _url = 'https://quarter-monkey.herokuapp.com/';

  static client.Socket _socket;

  static initialize() {
    if (_socket != null) return;
     _socket = client.io(
       _url,
       <String, dynamic>{
         'transports': ['websocket'],
         'autoConnect': false,
       },
     );


    _socket.on('connect', (_) => print('Connected'));
    _socket.on('reconnect_attempt', (_) => print('Reconnecting'));
    _socket.on('connecting', (_) => print('Connecting'));
    _socket.on('disconnect', (_) => print('Disconnected'));
    _socket.on('connect_error', (_) => print(_));
    _socket.on('error', (_) => print(_));

    _socket.connect();
  }

  static emit(String event, {dynamic arguments}) {
    initialize(); // Ensure it's initialized
    _socket.emit(event, arguments ?? {});
  }

  static subscribe(String event, Function function) {
    initialize(); // Ensure it's initialized
    _socket.on(event, function);
  }

  static unsubscribe(String event, Function function) {
    initialize(); // Ensure it's initialized
    _socket.off(event, function);
  }
}
```

**Note**

I keep getting connection timeout in flutter

Comment: Please check version's of socket.io server and client side. Needs to be both 3 or both 2. If correct then probably "cors" issue. If not please provide info about these and we can follow up :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply thanks you very much i downgraded the socket io on the server and it worked as a charm can u right an answer on the question so i can upvote it

Comment: It's fine I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: @AbdelrahmanShahda What are the versions you're using in server and client?

Comment: @carrasc0 I really don't remember since this was really old but I think socket version 3